# Messenger Bot approval

Tags: facebook, bots, messenger

I refer to a messenger bot (ChatPay) that we created and were seeking approval for. We noticed that the facebook team could not have a full experience on how the bot works as it is useful for registered users (as per the screen shot). The bot works with an application (ChatPay) from where  registration is invoked and bank transaction interfaces are displayed from (for security purposes).
How do I go about getting the bot approved? We could provide test credentials to the facebook team. The app is at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.craft.chatpay[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbC4e.png)

Comment: Describe to _them_ what steps they need to undertake to fully test your app. If they need to use special login credentials somewhere, then mention those in your review instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the regular review process, the Facebook users will test the bot and ask questions if need be.  They tested my bot and asked a few questions.

I have the Pages application on my phone so I saw all the interaction with the bot immediately.  You can type a personal message with Pages as well as have the bot respond.  I spoke with the Facebook test team this way.

Another idea is to put some boilerplate text on the bot that tells the testers the requirements.  You can make updates to the bot after the approval process to remove the instructions.  Until approval the general public cannot access the bot so your clients will not see the instructions.

Here is my [bot](https://m.me/dynamicmemorysolutions) if you would like to play around.  I'd be happy to help with your testing.